# How best to import a lot of text into an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have seemingly a lot of text that i need to get into my iphone app. It's not nearly as much as a book or anything but it would take quite some time to type it all out in xcode, and I'm sure thats not the best way. I read you can import an xml file or maybe a .txt, could someone please point me in the best direction, and maybe a tutorial or something to help me get started?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bundle any file you want with your application as a resource.  Just include it as part of your project, and then you can load it in your app as an `NSString*` or `NSData*`, whichever your prefer/whichever is most appropriate to your data type.

You can also transform the data however your would like, and write some new file that contains the transformed information, and then grab the new file and package *that* one with the app so that the transformation step no longer needs to be run.  For instance, maybe you want to parse your text data and prepopulate a Core Data model with it.  You could write the code that does this, grab the .sqlite database file that is generated, and then package the database file in the deployed version of your app so that everyone starts out with an already-populated data model.  If that happens to be your use-case here.

Answer (score 1):

What you mean by get text into my iphone app? Do you want to show the text in your application? If yes, why don't you just use the this NSString method:

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path 
      encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc 
      error:(NSError **)error
```

If your text needs to be formatted, I would recommend you to use webview to load formatted html files.